# PHP/MySQL How can I re-use ID's for blog articles instead of +1 each time

Tags: php, mysql

I've recently developed a CMS from scratch using PHP and MySQL running through Apache/phpmyadmin on a localhost.

Everything has gone very smoothly so far, visitors may view articles and navigate through the page successfully. Admins (created by an Admin on the CMS or in the MySQL schema) can log in, view articles, edit articles, view and edit users and delete articles.

My problem is that when articles are deleted, a next/previous button at the bottom (of any existing articles) with a function of

```
<?php if ($id != 1) : ?>

<a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $id - 1; ?>">Previous Article</a>

&nbsp; &nbsp;

<?php endif; ?>
```

which looks for a previously existing article with x-id, however since this article was deleted it no longer exists. Is there any way to remove the article id as the article is deleted, thus freeing up that article id again?

I can manually reset the id to 0,1,2,3... etc. in the schema on phpmyadmin, but I'd like to apply some logic in order to make this system work flawlessly.

Many thanks for you help, if I get time I'll upload the CMS to my web server so that it can be viewed freely.

~Myles

EDIT: a video can be viewed here: http://youtu.be/F8LU1jei3E4

Comment: for your pagniation you need to allow for missing id's its pretty easy to do using count and limit commands in sql as they are id independant ie: count 3 could be id anything.  Just google around a little on php pagination you should be able to copy and paste with a few minor modifications.

Comment: Can't you just do as everybody else and retrieve the next/prev IDs from database instead of calculating them? It doesn't make sense that you have let's say 500 articles and the latest one gets into 20th position.

Comment: So in theory I could use MAX ID for the next button?

Comment: max id would return you to the newest article but if you have 10 article per page your on page 3 at the moment you can select limit (3x30,4x10) etc to pull back the next 10 article id's for your page 4 etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by querying based on `id`.

Previous article:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id < ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Next article:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id > ? ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks tadman,

Theoretically this makes the most sense to me, I'm essentially replacing the echo of "$id -1" with "$id <$id"

However, I'm unsure how this would fit into my current code! Any advice?  Feel free to use my example above which is taken straight from the article template

Comment: `$id < $id` makes no sense. It should be `id < ?` where `?` is the escaped value of the `$id` in question. If you're [using PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) this is how you write the statement. Try `id=<?php echo $id ?>&dir=next` for your "next" link, and same idea for `prev`, and use the value of `$_GET['dir']` to determine which query to use.

Answer (score 0):

So for your pagination it is always better to play with SQL's LIMIT.
Instead of using your id for a query like that:

```
'SELECT * FROM articles WHERE article_id=' . $id
```

(it is not a safe query, it's just to show you)

So instead of this query, yours should look like this one:

```
'SELECT * FROM articles LIMIT ' . $id . ', 1;'
```

This will not return you the article with the id $id, but the $id'th article.
Hope it's clear for you.

Comment: Using an offset in MySQL is really slow for large offsets.

Comment: Unless you use late row lookups and InnoDB. also, having 1 million records and using regular approach is still quick, and it's doubtful a simple blog will have 1 million articles.